# JavaScript to show <div> after a certain date

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I believe this is a relatively simple question (a JavaScript noob here), but I can't seem to find a thread for this particular date function. I am doing website migration for an academic society from a PHP-based site to a drupal CMS. Some of the PHP has obviously broken and I'm trying to replace simple scripts with Javascript. One issue that is giving me a lot of trouble is how to get a text to appear only AFTER a certain date. In PHP my functioning code is:

```
<?php if (date('YmdH') > 2018011710 ) { ?>
    <p class="error">Please note that the deadline for submitting proposals has passed.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

So I need something in JavaScript to do the same. Here is what I came up with (I apologize in advance for my sloppy code as I'm a beginner with JavaScript):

First CSS to hide the DIV:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .DateDiv { display: none;}
</style>
```

Then the div itself:

```
<div class="DateDiv">
    <h3>Please note that the deadline for submitting proposals has passed.</h3>
</div>
```

Finally, my JavaScript, which is not working:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
      dd = '0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
      mm = '0'+mm
    } 

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    // show only if current date is after January 16, 20018
    if (today > 0, 16, 2018) {
      $(".DateDiv").show();
    }
  });
</script>
```

If anyone could help me sort this out I would be very grateful. If I'm going about this in a manner that is more complicated than it needs to be I'd also appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am not asking to compare two dates, but to display a text after a certain date.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Implementing security checks in the frontend only isn't a good idea, everyone with a bit of knowledge could alter the check and submit after the deadline.

Comment: That condition ` (today > 0, 16, 2018)` does not look like valid JS code after all...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: @Appleshell yes, but the CMS will not allow server-side code like PHP. I don't care if a user submits a proposal late as long as the text at the top of the page lets them know that the deadline has passed. Unless you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just might want to do something like this:

```
if (new Date() >= new Date(2018, 0, 16))
```

months always start at 0 while days start at 1. don't ask why.

this is how the constructor is defined:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hour [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

just go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for in-depth details about `Date()`

Comment: I could imagine that months start with 0 because then you can use a simple array to translate the month number into a month name.

Comment: Brilliant. That did the trick and was super easy. Thank you so much and to have the answer within seconds!

Comment: first argument is always year, then month, then day, then hours, then minutes, then seconds

Comment: and the month is the only argument that counts from 0

Comment: `new Date().getDay()` is kind of similar too. starts at 0 but goes from sunday to saturday instead of monday to sunday

Comment: you might want to go there for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @GottZ Thank you. Very useful information for this noob.

Comment: no problem. if it helped and solved your problem feel free to accept this answer :D

Comment: @Gottz I do't see where I can do that, but I would be happy to.

Comment: @beingbecoming There should be a checkmark next to the answer, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Gottz Got it. Thanks again. Good Day.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//show only if current date is after January 16, 20018
var date_to_check_with = new Date("20180116").getTime();

//.getTime() will give time in milliseconds (epoch time) 
var current_date = new Date().getTime();

console.log(date_to_check_with < current_date);
```